# Route jackd to discord.py

Tags: python, audio, python3, streaming, jack

Currently, I am trying to take audio output from jackd and pipe it into a discord voice chat. This solution doe not seem to work, but [this](https://github.com/QiCuiHub/discord-audio-pipe) solution supposedly works. What is happening that my solution doesn't work, and the other one does. Can I make a solution similar to that of the solution on the github repository?

```
import discord  
from discord.ext import commands  
from discord.utils import get  
import os
#import jack
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient


#start ffmpeg encoding magic.
os.system("ffmpeg -f jack -i stream_input -acodec libmp3lame -y stream.mp3 &> ffmpeg.log&")





# start jackd client stuff
#jack_client = jack.Client('Campfire')
#jack_client.inports.register('stream_input')



#Some variables. PLEASE ADJUST."
Client_Prefix= '>'
token= 'Nah'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = Client_Prefix)



#discord bot voice stuff 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as " + client.user.name + ".\n")
    print("Prefix is " + Client_Prefix + "\n")
    print('Status: armed')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Joining the campfire.')
    global voice
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
        print("The bot has connected to a voice channel.")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
        print("The bot has disconnected from a voice channel")
        await ctx.send("Leaving the campfire")
    else:
        print("Error: I am not currently at a campfire")
        await ctx.send("I am not currently at a campfire.")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def stoke(ctx):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("stream.mp3")
    #try:
        #if song_there:
            #os.remove("stream.mp3")
            #print("Removed old campfire ashes.")
            #await ctx.send("Removed old campfire ashes.")
    #except PermissionError:
        #print("Unable to remove old ashes. Bulldozing required.")
        #await ctx.send("Unable to remove old ashes. Bulldozing required.")
        #return

    await ctx.send("Tuning the mystical instrument.")

    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("stream.mp3"))
client.run(token)
```